# Flutter draw clipPath

Tags: flutter

I want to draw two clip-paths on the same page. Unfortunately, I am not successful in it.

Sample

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We can appreciate that you are struggling with something, but your question includes absolutely no information about the problem you're facing. Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

Separate your page into multiple layouts e.g. `Stack` as a parent and two widgets e.g. `Container` and clip each path with its own `Clipper`.

Example:

```
return Stack(
  children: [
    Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: ClipPath(
                clipper: MyCustomClipper1(),
                child: SizedBox(
                width: 320,
                height: 240,
                child: Container(),
       ),
    ),
    Container(
         alignment: Alignment.center,
         child: ClipPath(
                  clipper: MyCustomClipper2(),
                  child: SizedBox(
                  width: 320,
                  height: 240,
                  child: Container(),
        ),
     ),
  ],
);
```

Maybe I have few mistakes since I wrote the code directly here, feel free to ask for more details, maybe I can help.